# Choosing size of Cloud SQL Instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have a MySQL database whose tables Weight in at 40GB, and when I run the command "top -c" it shows that MySQL is using 14GB of RAM.

In order to migrate this database to Cloud SQL, do I have to maintain the same amount of ram? Or does the way that Cloud SQL manage indexes and memory mean that I can choose a server is less RAM?  Are there tools that will allow me to know if performance is suffering due to lack of RAM?

Thanks for your feedback

Regards,
Marcelo

Answer (score 1):

In general, you would not have to maintain that same amount of RAM.  MySQL is caching data in RAM for fast access, so less RAM = slower queries.

Before migrating to the cloud, I'd run some test using [MySQL benchmarks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-benchmarks.html), which should give you some empirical numbers to help make your decision as to the amount of RAM you need.